# Converting a void to return something

Tags: c++

I have this void function in c++

```
void DrawFace(cv::Mat img, Window face)
{
    int x1 = face.x;
    int y1 = face.y;
    int x2 = face.width + face.x - 1;
    int y2 = face.width + face.y - 1;
    int centerX = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    int centerY = (y1 + y2) / 2;
    std::vector<cv::Point> pointList;
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x1, y1, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x1, y2, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x2, y2, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x2, y1, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    DrawLine(img, pointList);
}
```

i wanted this to return me just the pointList vector for which i made this change

```
void Drawface(cv::Mat img, Window face) 
{
    int x1 = face.x;
    int y1 = face.y;
    int x2 = face.width + face.x - 1;
    int y2 = face.width + face.y - 1;
    int centerX = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    int centerY = (y1 + y2) / 2;
    std::vector<cv::Point> pointList;
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x1, y1, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x1, y2, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x2, y2, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x2, y1, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    return pointList
}
```

It would be really helpful if somebody could point out where i have gone wrong and what changes i could make.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change the signature of the function to `std::vector<cv::Point> Drawface(cv::Mat img, Window face)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Ryan Great! Note that this is exactly the same as Vittorio suggests in his answer if you read it closely ("_....return type is still `void`. You need to change it to reflect the changes in the body_").

Comment: Easy alternative - change declaration "void Drawface(cv::Mat img, Window face)" and add a reference pointList to the parameter list:  "void Drawface(cv::Mat img, Window face, std::vector<cv::Point>& pointList)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function's return type is still `void`. You need to change it to reflect the changes in the body. Also, missing a semicolon after `return pointList`.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks , i have added the semicolon, i have also removed the void.Now it looks like `Drawface(cv::Mat img, Window face)` ,is this okay?

Comment: No. You obviously need to read a beginner C++ book. StackOverflow is not the right place to help you with the basics such as function signatures. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Okay ,cool .Thanks for the help though ,ill look into it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare the return type of the function.

```
std::vector<cv::Point> Drawface(cv::Mat img, Window face) 
{
    int x1 = face.x;
    int y1 = face.y;
    int x2 = face.width + face.x - 1;
    int y2 = face.width + face.y - 1;
    int centerX = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    int centerY = (y1 + y2) / 2;
    std::vector<cv::Point> pointList;
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x1, y1, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x1, y2, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x2, y2, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    pointList.push_back(RotatePoint(x2, y1, centerX, centerY, face.angle));
    return pointList;
}
```